# Отсортировать по алфавиту односвязный список

Tags: c++, c, сортировка, list

Здавствуйте. В общем мне нужно отсортировать список по анлийскому алфавиту, то есть например у нас есть вот такие две строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но нужно, чтобы строка с буквой А была раньше B.
Увы не знаю, как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Вот пример моей функции:

```
    void sort(struct spis **Begin) {
        struct spis* Current = *Begin, *Previous = Current;
        int m;
        while (Current) {

            if (strcmp(Current->name,Current->Next->name)>0) {
                Previous = Current;
                Current = Current->Next;
            }
                else
                {
                     Current->Next=Current;     
                    Current = Previous->Next;
                }
            }
        }

Структура такая:

    struct spis {
        char name[45];
        float sc;
        float cnt;
        double sq;
        struct spis *Next;

    };

Вот моя функция заполнения списка: 
struct spis* CreateList(void)
{
    struct spis* Begin = NULL, *Previous = NULL,*Current = NULL;
double sqx;
int i=0;

int size=1;
    char Ok = 'y';
    while (Ok=='y')
    {       
        Current =(struct spis*)malloc(sizeof(struct spis));
        if (Begin == NULL)
            Begin = Current;
        else Previous->Next = Current;
        Previous = Current;

        for (i; i < size; i++) {
            printf("%d. Введите: название, школу, количество, площадь >", i + 1);
            scanf("%s", &Current->name);
            scanf_s("%f", &Current->sc);
            scanf_s("%f", &Current->cnt);
            scanf_s("%lf", &sqx); Current->sq = sqx;        
        }
    fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nContinue? (Y/N):");
        Ok = _getch();  cout << endl;
    size++;
    }

    Previous->Next = NULL;
    return Begin;
}
```

Comment: в вопросе фигурирует `c++` а в коде явно `c` - как это понимать? Всмысле вам нужно решение на `c` или `c++`?

Comment: Это абсолютно не имеет роли на каком языке будет решение, но примерно я показал как в моей функции. Да в моем коде присутствует смесь и с, и с++

Comment: @t1nzy,  сортировка односвязного списка проще всего программируется *сортировкой вставками*. Абсолютно естественно. Во внешнем цикле убираете первый элемент из исходного списка (пока он не станет пустым). Во вложенном вставляете на нужное место в новый список. В конце он получается отсортированным и вы возвращаете указатель на его начало, который присваиваете указателюю на исходный список.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пара простых функций (на основе вашей структуры односвязного списка, в принципе, их можно обобщить для произвольной структуры, добавив в аргументы вызова функции пользователя для доступа к Next и сравнения).

Вставка в сортированный список (возможно пустой, возможно из одного элемента)

```
struct spis *
insert_srt (struct spis *list, struct spis *item)
{
  if (!list || strcmp(item->name, list->name) < 0) {
    item->Next = list;
    list = item;
  } else {
    for (struct spis *p = list; p; p = p->Next)
      if (p->Next == 0 || strcmp(item->name, p->Next->name) < 0) {
         item->Next = p->Next;
         p->Next = item;
         break;
      }
  }

  return list;
}
```

Сортировка списка

```
struct spis *
sort_list (struct spis *list)
{
  struct spis *sl = 0;

  while (list) {
    struct spis *p = list;
    list = list->Next;
    sl = insert_srt(sl, p);
  }

  return sl;
}
```

Надеюсь, с вводом начального списка и вызовом `sort_list()` вы справитесь сами.

---

**Update 1**

Попробовал с вашей функцией

```
void
print_list (struct spis *p)
{
  while (p) {
    printf("%s %f %f %f\n", p->name, p->sc, p->cnt, p->sq);
    p = p->Next;
  }
}


struct spis* CreateList(void)
{
  struct spis* Begin = NULL, *Previous = NULL,*Current = NULL;
  double sqx;
  int i=0;

  int size=1;
  char Ok = 'y';
  while (Ok=='y')
    {       
      Current =(struct spis*)malloc(sizeof(struct spis));
      if (Begin == NULL)
    Begin = Current;
      else Previous->Next = Current;
      Previous = Current;

      //        for (i; i < size; i++) {
      printf("%d. Введите: название, школу, количество, площадь >", size);
      scanf("%s", Current->name);
      scanf("%f", &Current->sc);
      scanf("%f", &Current->cnt);
      scanf("%lf", &sqx); Current->sq = sqx;        
      //        }
      fflush(stdin);

      printf("\nContinue? (Y/N):");
      char buf[100];
      scanf("%s", buf);
      Ok = buf[0];
      //Ok = getchar();
      //    cout << endl;
      puts("");
      size++;
    }

  Previous->Next = NULL;
  return Begin;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct spis *list = CreateList();

  puts("-----");

  list = sort_list(list);
  print_list(list);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Оттранслировал и запустил

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc -g list_insert_sort.c
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
1. Введите: название, школу, количество, площадь >m 1 2 3

Continue? (Y/N):y

2. Введите: название, школу, количество, площадь >a 2 3 4

Continue? (Y/N):y

3. Введите: название, школу, количество, площадь >z 7 6 4

Continue? (Y/N):y

4. Введите: название, школу, количество, площадь >b 6 4 3

Continue? (Y/N):n

-----
a 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000
b 6.000000 4.000000 3.000000
m 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000
z 7.000000 6.000000 4.000000
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

У меня вроде сортирует?

Comment: Не знаю, почему то не работает, ввёл как у вас и подставил свои переменные, которые использую и почему-то не работает. Я добавил свою функцию заполнения списка в начальный вопрос, может вы подскажите именно как под него сделать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Что именно не работает? Какие исходные данные, что печатает до сортировки и что после нее.

Comment: В общем, ничего не просиходит, я ввожу, допустим: M 4 4 43, нажимаю энтер, далее продолжаю и еще пишу, допустим: A 5 54 53. То есть ввожу случайные числа и буквы которые потом надо сменить. Печатаю список, ряд с буквой М стоит первый, далее ряд с буквой А, нажимаю в меню функцию сортировки, далее опять нажимаю пропечатать - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Сейчас попробую у себя законченный вариант. Только у меня Линукс, я наверное немного изменю вашу функцию ввода.

Comment: Сделал пример в **update**